# Get file offset from a loaded DLL's function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, offset, virtual-address-space

I'd like to ask, how could I locate a specific *(exported)* function inside a DLL. For example I'd like to locate ReadProcessMemory inside Kernel32. I wouldn't like to rely on Import table, I'd like to locate different APIs based on their addresses what I get with a custom function.

I tried to make a small research on VA, RVA & File offsets, but I didn't succeed. Here's an example which I tried, but it isn't working *(returns 0 in all cases)*:

```
DWORD Rva2Offset(DWORD dwRva, UINT_PTR uiBaseAddress)
{
    WORD wIndex = 0;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSectionHeader = NULL;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders = NULL;

    pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) (uiBaseAddress + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) uiBaseAddress)->e_lfanew);
    pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) ((UINT_PTR) (&pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader) + pNtHeaders->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);

    if (dwRva < pSectionHeader[0].PointerToRawData)
        return dwRva;

    for (wIndex = 0; wIndex < pNtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; wIndex++)
    {
        if (dwRva >= pSectionHeader[wIndex].VirtualAddress && dwRva < (pSectionHeader[wIndex].VirtualAddress + pSectionHeader[wIndex].SizeOfRawData))
            return (dwRva - pSectionHeader[wIndex].VirtualAddress + pSectionHeader[wIndex].PointerToRawData);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you help me how could I accomplish this simple task?

Thank you.

*P.s.: I'm not sticking to the function above, both if you can point out what's the problem, or give a better source would be awesome.*

Comment: Damn, no answers? :/

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the relative virtual address

```
uintptr_t baseAddr = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle("nameOfExe.exe");
uintptr_t relativeAddr = functionAddress - baseAddr;
```

This converts relative virtual address to File offset:

```
DWORD RVAToFileOffset(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32* pNtHdr, DWORD dwRVA)
{
int i;
WORD wSections;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSectionHdr;

pSectionHdr = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNtHdr);
wSections = pNtHdr->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

for (i = 0; i < wSections; i++)
{
if (pSectionHdr->VirtualAddress <= dwRVA)
if ((pSectionHdr->VirtualAddress + pSectionHdr->Misc.VirtualSize) > dwRVA)
{
dwRVA -= pSectionHdr->VirtualAddress;
  dwRVA += pSectionHdr->PointerToRawData;

return (dwRVA);
}

pSectionHdr++;
}

return (-1);
}
```